# Can't boot into recovery or downloading mode on galaxy player. Is it hardbricked?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, factory-reset, unbricking

I have a galaxy player 5.0 -old build and everything, but I like to experiment with it- and i wiped cache and did a factory reset and tried to reboot, and for some reason wouldn't want to boot up. So i just killed it, and tried to re-flash the stock firmware(had been rooted and some other stuff), and it failed, and now it just has a pic of [phone--triangle with !-- computer]. I can't get it to go anywhere- recovery mode, downloading mode, can't even turn it off without taking the battery out. My question is, am i done for? Is it hardbricked?

Comment: When you put the battery back in, does it wait for you to hold the Power button in order to boot, or does it boot on its own?

Comment: It waits for me to hold the power button in

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not hardbricked, only softbricked. The phone with triangle and exclamation mark is telling that you didn't flash properly. In that case it should still allow you to boot into download mode. Remove battery, put it back in and hold the appropriate buttons to boot into download mode and then reflash rom

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I tried that I don't know how many times :(. Isn't there something you can do when you take the battery out, like hold the power button for awhile before putting it back in? I tried all kinds of stuff like that, but no go

Comment: Well sometimes buttons don't work and sometimes you can only boot after several attempts. Try these anyway: Pwr+vol up, Pwr+vol down, All keys pressed simultaneously, one of them should force it to reboot. As soon as you see it turn off, press keys for download mode. Follow this guide if you get stuck in bootloop https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1850600

Comment: That still didn't help. Going to see if those little dongles you can get on Ebay to force the device into download mode can help at all.